# Why does Connection.exec_driver_sql have inconsistent parameter parsing for queries with the IN operator?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

These two queries are semantically identical, but one of them succeeds and the other one fails. The only difference is in the `WHERE` clause, where the two operands of the `OR` operator have been switched.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:pwd@host:port/db', 

# Query succeeds (and does what's expected)
with engine.connect() as cn:
    cn.exec_driver_sql(
        f'UPDATE table SET column = "value" WHERE id = %s OR id IN %s', 
        (3, (1, 2))
    )

# Query fails
with engine.connect() as cn:
    cn.exec_driver_sql(
        f'UPDATE table SET column = "value" WHERE id IN %s OR id = %s', 
        ((1, 2), 3)
    )
```

Output of the failed query:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

It seems that sqlalchemy argument parsing is dependant on the type of the first argument. If the first one if a tuple, the query fails, if it is a int/float/str, it succeeds.

The workaround I've found so far is to use named arguments:

```py
# Query succeeds
with engine.connect() as cn:
    cn.exec_driver_sql(
        f'UPDATE table SET column = "value" WHERE id IN %(arg1)s OR id = %(arg2)s', 
        {'arg1': (1, 2), 'arg2': 3}
    )
```

However it is more verbose and I don't want to use this everywhere. Also note that PyMySQL cursor's `execute` method accepted both queries.

**Is there a reason for this behaviour?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem lies in [DefaultExecutionContext._init_statement](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/293cb14e2198c11e9c8b71454f35c0ff92dc25ab/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py#L1105) classmethod.

```py
...
        if not parameters:
            ...
        elif isinstance(parameters[0], dialect.execute_sequence_format):
            self.parameters = parameters
        elif isinstance(parameters[0], dict):
            ...
        else:
            self.parameters = [
                dialect.execute_sequence_format(p) for p in parameters
            ]

        self.executemany = len(parameters) > 1
```

`isinstance(parameters[0], dialect.execute_sequence_format)` is checking whether the first element of `parameters` is a `tuple`.  This *seems* to be heuristic for efficiently detecting an `executemany` scenario: probably it should check that all the elements are tuples and of equal length*.  As it is values `((1, 2), 3)` will cause the equivalent of

```py
cursor.executemany(sql, [(1, 2), 3])
```

and syntactically invalid statements like

```sql
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id IN 1 OR id = 2
--                         ^^^^
```

Wrapping the parameters in a `list` fixes the problem, since `len(parameters)` will no longer be greater than one.

```py
with engine.connect() as cn:
    cn.exec_driver_sql(
        f'UPDATE table SET column = "value" WHERE id IN %s OR id = %s', 
        [((1, 2), 3)]
    )
```

Obviously this is a workaround on top of a heuristic, so it may not work in every possible situation.  It's probably worth opening a [discussion](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions) on GitHub to explore whether this is a bug that should be fixed.

---

* Passing a tuple to create parenthesised values for `...IN %s` or `...VALUES %s` is not supported by all drivers, so it's not that bad a heuristic.

Comment: The OP opened [this discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/7820).